# How to set an OpenCV window to be a Click-through window?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

i have a problem making my window a "click-through" window.
I have tried some methods i found online for windowsAPI but with no luck, the mouse won't pass  through the created window.

My OS is Windows 10.

Any solutions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally found the problem with the windows API functions. the handle passed to them was wrong, the opencv cvGetWindowHandle() returns the wrong handle, using the handle return from FindWindow() i was able to make my window click-through.

```
//-Init an opencv window
cv::namedWindow("foo");

HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,"foo"); //-Work!
HWND hwnd = (HWND)cvGetWindowHandle("foo");//-Doesn't Work.

//-Set window to be click-through.
LONG lExStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
lExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED;
SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle);

//-Set the window to  always be on top.
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```